# Firebase rule "resource.data.uid" dont work with a stream

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

currently I am implementing the firebase rules into my project. I implemented reading and writing and it works really well.

My problem right now is a stream in combination with the rule "resource.data.uid".

My Firebase hirrarchy looks like following:
[image]

My selected rules are like following:

```
match /Chats/{uuid}/general/{uuid}{
  allow read: if isSignedIn() && isOwner(resource.data.uid);
  allow write: if isSignedIn();
}

function isSignedIn() {
  return request.auth != null;
}

function isOwner(userId) {
  return request.auth.uid == userId;
}
```

I made a direct read request with the rule and a direct read request works perfectly!

If I use my stream function to the document something really interessting happens. In the first run I get the data (I also get the data when I add "false" to my rules!!) but after some milliseconds my handler jumps into error and say no permission. I try to modify the rule in all possibilities but I am not able to bring my stream to run with this rules.

My Stream in Flutter looks like this:

```
static Stream<List<ChatUsersGeneral>> getUsers(String myuuid) =>
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Chats/$myuuid/general')
        .orderBy('lastMessage', descending: true)
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
        .map((document) => ChatUsersGeneral.fromJson(document.data())).toList());
```

When I change my rules to the following one it also works. It looks like the command resource.data.uid is not working in combination with a stream.

```
match /Chats/{uuid}/general/{uuid}{
  allow read: if isSignedIn() && uuid == '7ea44a84-32435-23ec-8d3d-000000000286';
  allow write: if isSignedIn();
}
```

I hope i was able to explain my problem and somebody here can help me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Security rules don't filter data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters), but instead merely ensure that the code only accesses data that is allowed to access. Since your rules only allow the user to access documents where the `uid` field matches the logged-in user, your code should also only request those documents.

So in code:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('Chats/$myuuid/general')
    .where('uid', isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid) // 
    .orderBy('lastMessage', descending: true)
    .snapshots()
```

Now the code requests only documents where it is the owner, which matches the requirement of your security rules.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast answer! the issue is still there. And currently I only have one document inside. i also tried one more step. If I change the rule to a constant value with the users uid it works : request.auth.uid == 'QWuz4mSF9ifrSbGRLEHEHuzpDo92';. If I change it back to request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid it again stop working.

Comment: You said that about testing with a hard-coded UID already, so no need to repeat it here. --- Did you read the link I provided about how security rules are not filters? And does it make sense with that and my explanation on why your current rules don't work, and how the change I show would fix that problem at least? There may be other problems, but as far as I can see this is one of them.

Comment: Hi Frank van puffelen, Thank you very much!!! The 2nd problem was that I of course had to add an index into firebase if I use the where() function. Now it works! You safed my weekend